# I get java.util.NoSuchElementException when I want to read something from the keyboard

Tags: java

I want to make a simple app that reads a string from the keyboard and prints it with a message afterwards. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class HelloWorld {   
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter an integer");
        int myint = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(myint+ " <- that's the string");     
    }    
}
```

Something is wrong because I get an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:25)

How can I solve this?

Comment: and what is your input ??

Comment: I cannot write anything, when I compile the code I get that message

Comment: Are you using BlueJ? It seems there is a problem with the terminal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126927/scanner-doesnt-work-in-blue-j-java . Compile and run the program from command line and check. It works OK with eclipse.

Comment: I copied your code and ran in eclipse IDE. it worked fine for me.

Comment: @rishabhagarwal you're right. I tried on a java online fiddle and it didn't work but I tried again in eclipse and it did work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `scanner.hasNext()` and `scanner.hasNextInt()`.

```
  // find the next int token and print it
  // loop for the whole scanner
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {

     // if the next is a int, print "Found" and the int
     if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Found " + scanner.nextInt());
     }
     // if no int is found, print "Not found" and the token
     System.out.println("Not found " + scanner.next());
  }
```